# simple pic10f204 C programing

Tags: c, pic, gpio

I'm new to microcontrollers and picked out a PIC10f204. I am using MPLAB XIDE with the free XC8 C compiler.

I'm trying to slowly learn right now. All i am trying to do is set GPIO bit 0, which is the GP0 pin out, to out put high.

So far my code looks like this but I am not measuring 5V from the pin GP0 or any of the other GPIO pins, except GP3.

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF      // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protect (Code protection off)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // Master Clear Enable (GP3/MCLR pin fuction is digital I/O, MCLR internally tied to VDD)

int main(void) {

    OSCCAL= 0x00;
    TRISGPIO = 0x00;
    GPIO= 0xFF;

    return 0; // we should never reach this
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll guess you forgot the required pull-up register.  Connect the output with a 10k resistor to Vdd, usually one is provided on the dev board.  electronics.stackexchange.com is the best place for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks Hans,I tried the pull up but still no go. right now I don't have any thing connected to the micro controller except for the pickit3 and I'm measuring outputs with a multi-meter. I just want to make sure my program is actually outputting 5v at the Output pins, but they are still at 0V. I even tried to just program MCLRE to ON but I still get 5v out from the GP3/MCLR pin. When I erase the memory on the PIC MCLR pin goes back to 0v. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple changes might help:

1) Try adding an infinite loop in your code. The program on a microcontroller should follow a general structure of initialization functions followed by an infinite loop.

2) Looking at the datasheet for the PIC10F204, it says that pin 3 is input only. Try modifying as follows: TRISGPIO = 0x08;

I modified your code below to illustrate this. Hopefully this works for you.

```
int main(void) {

    // PIC Initializations should go here
    OSCCAL= 0x00;
    CMCON0 = 0x51;
    TRISGPIO = 0x08;
    GPIO= 0xFF;

    while(1) {
        // Program main loop (should never end)
    }

    return 0; // we should never reach this
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo for the response. I tried your modified code and added the PIC Initialization under main. The code compiled and I was able to program the PIC, but still no 5v on the GPIO pins. Your right GP3 is an input and I double checked that I was actually programming the micro by erasing the program from the pic and read 0v on GP3. When I reloaded the program on the pic I'm guessing MCLRE off puts GP3 on high and I read 5v. I was wondering if I am missing some sort of a clock setting or is there something else that can prevent me from setting the GPIO ports to high? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi o10c01o, 

I took another look at the datasheet for the PIC. It seems that the GP0 pin is multiplexed with the comparator module, and Table 5-1 indicates that the CIN+ functionality of the GP0 pin has priority over the TRIS GPIO functionality. So we need to add another configuration command before setting the pin to output and setting the logic level to high. 

Take a look at page 37 of the datasheet: "Comparator Module". We have to disable and turn off the comparator. Try adding the following line immediately after OSCCAL = 0x00:

    CMCON0 = 0x51;

Let me know if this works!